# During a Chase scene....

Tags: reverb

How do you use reverb?

The scene is indoor, it goes from a bathroom with some slow motion, and then he shoots a hole in the wall which turns out to be a video game wall and runs some more down a hallway but before the hallway cut there is a Heads up display showing xray view of him, his pursuers, and the walls of the building. 3 people are chasing him and there is a shootout in the bathroom where the door is splintered to pieces.

Answer (score 3):

I really think you will need to elaborate on your question for anybody to be able to answer this one. Is it a car chase foot chase, indoor, outdoor, what is chasing them, animal, monster human ???? Give some specifics and I am sure somebody will be able to help.

Comment: it's indoor, it goes from a bathroom with some slow motion, and then he shoots a hole in the wall which turns out to be a video game wall and runs some more down a hallway but before the hallway cut there is a Heads up display showing xray view of him, his pursuers, and the walls of the building.  3 people are chasing him and there is a shootout in the bathroom where the door is splintered to pieces.

Comment: I hold my breath while reading your chase scene! 

Answer (score 1):

I would start with reality - what would it really sound like, and then make it a bit bigger.  Chase scenes are generally made to sound much bigger than life.  One thing I like to do in chase scenes are take big sounding rooms and gate the decay a bit, so you have the big sound without the sloppiness of a long decay.  Makes it sound much tighter, much more machine-like, much more deliberate and fast paced.  They did a ton of that in the Bourne movies.

Don't saturate too much, that makes it sound a bit too dreamy.  Also, I'd use a lot of slap echo.  There's a lot of slap back indoors, especially in long hallways and bigger bathrooms (like public ones).  That can really help make your sounds sound bigger as well